# How to find out the ratio of helpful vs declined flags using data.SE?

Tags: support, data-explorer

*Intro:* I've got an idea to propose a badge, that will unlike existing flag badges (Citizen Patrol: First flagged post; Deputy: Raise 80 helpful flags; Marshal: Raise 500 helpful flags) encourage rising only helpful flags (or flagging more carefully, I may say). But the problem-solving idea is only worth discussing if there's actually a problem.

Hence I'd like to find out some statistics regarding helpful vs declined (vs aged away?) flags ratio. The simplest thing to look at is actually that ratio (while next steps would be to check it for posts, comments, see distribution by total number of flags raised by user etc).

The problem is: [at data.SE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new) in Database Schema I can see only FlagTypes table and PendingFlags. But what about resolved flags? Is data about them available? How do I create a request calculating the overall `helpful : declined` ratio?

Comment: The number and type of flags raised nor their resolution is available in the public SEDE schema. Needs SE staff to run a query on the internal SEDE instance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Information on resolved flags is not available in Data Explorer.

(And I'm not fond of the idea of placing further emphasis on declined flags; don't we have enough **Y U DECLINE** posts already? There's be even more indignation if declined flags in addition set back the user's progress toward a badge.)

Comment: Right, thanks. Your point about indignation is somewhat worthy noting; however, without stats there's not much sense in discussing the idea, I guess.